# Accessing parent class object through thread

Tags: java

My question is, In my code I have made a JTable in main class. Now I am making a thread To do some task and to collect some data which i want to fill in the JTable as soon as the thread collects it. This thread should run for a while. So Can I access the JTable of main class through the Thread created.

EDIT: I'm providing my code here.

**Test.java**

```
package test;


import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import java.awt.*;

public class Test implements ActionListener {

 Thread t;
 JTable table;
 JScrollPane scrollPane;
 JButton b;
 JFrame frame;


 public void body() {

  frame = new JFrame("TableDemo");
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

  table = new JTable(new MyTableModel());
  table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
  table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

  scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
  frame.add(scrollPane);

  b = new JButton("OK");
  frame.add(b);

  thread a = new thread(new MyTableModel());
  t = new Thread(a);

  frame.pack();
  frame.setVisible(true);

  b.addActionListener(this);

 }


 public static void main(String[] args) {

  new Test().body();

 }


 @Override
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

  t.start();

 }
}


class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

 private String[] columnNames = {
  "First Name",
  "Last Name",
  "Sport"
 };

 private Object[][] data = {
  {
   "a",
   "a",
   "a"
  }
 };

 @Override
 public int getColumnCount() {
  return columnNames.length;
 }

 public int getRowCount() {
  return data.length;
 }

 public String getColumnName(int col) {
  return columnNames[col];
 }

 public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
  return data[row][col];
 }
 public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
  return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
 }
 public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
  if (col < 3) {
   return false;
  } else {
   return true;
  }
 }
 public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
  data[row][col] = value;
  fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
 }

}
```

**thread.java**

```
package test;

public class thread implements Runnable {

  MyTableModel model;

    thread(MyTableModel model){
        this.model = model;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Object aa = "new value";
        this.model.setValueAt(aa, 0, 0);
        System.out.println(this.model.getValueAt(0, 0));
    }       

}
```

What I actually want is The value at 0,0 on the display screen of the JTable should Change from "a" to "new value".

Please give some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a thread you actually create a Runnable class, either by extending Thread or implementing Runnable. So you will have your own class such as this

```
 MyClass implements Runnable {
     public void run() { ... your work here ... }
 }
```

Simply pass any objects you like to the constructor of this class

```
 MyClass implements Runnable {


     JTable m_jtable;

     public MyClass( JTable theTable ) { m_jtable = theTable; }

     public void run() { do things with m_jtable }
 }
```

Comment: I did this but the work I'm doing with m_jtable is reflecting in that only.
It is not reflecting in the actual object I'm passing into the MyClass, and that's what I want.
Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while I've been doing Swing programming, but you probably want to have your Thread updating table's model instead of messing with JTable itself. In any case it will have a model, whether you create it or not.

So you should have the Thread that is collecting the data have a reference to the *model*, and once collection is done, fire some events in order to have the table updated (for instance http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableDataChanged()).

You should avoid littering your code with public references to internals of your application, i.e. do not have your table/model available as a public variable somewhere. Know where your objects live, it keep things tidy.

*EDIT:*

So you would have your model:

```
public class MyModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    private ClassDescribingYourData data;

    public void update(ClassDescribingYourData data) {
        this.data = data;
        fireTableDataChanged();
    }
}
```

And your data collector:

```
public class DataCollector implements Runnable {
    private final MyModel model;

    public DataCollector(MyModel model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public void run() {
        //1. collect data
        collectedData = ..
        //2. update model
        this.model.update(collectedData);
    }
 }
```

Then, you'd either use some Executor or simply do:

```
 DataCollector collector = new DataCollector(referenceToYourModel);
 new Thread(collector).start();
```

Above is not a complete implementation but I hope it explains the idea.

Comment: Can you tell me, how can I get my thread a reference to the model.

Comment: I updated my answer with pseudo-java regarding how the logic would go about.

Comment: I tried the thing you said above, but it didn't helped.
Actually the data of the object declared in the DataCollector is getting changed and not of the object I'm passing into the DataCollector Class.
Please give any other alternative....

Comment: In my example above, `update` method of `MyModel` is used to pass fresh data to the model. Model class, however, is not fully implemented above. Most importantly, `getValueAt` is missing. How this would work in your case depends on your data (`ClassDescribingYourData` in my example).

Comment: You're issue is that the Thread and JTable do _not_ share the same model - you provide both with `new MyTableModel`. So even though your Thread does update a value in the model, JTable can not render the change as it is using _different_ model. Also, you should not name your classes a) starting with lowercase, b) same name as library class (thread vs Thread), c) re-start a Thread.

Comment: Thanks. Done it. Now It's happening what I wanted.